# Are questions about writing techniques on topic here?

Tags: discussion, scope

When we write questions on this site, are we allowed to ask questions on writing techniques?

Research:

> According to Area 51:
>
> > Beta Q&A site for scholars and enthusiasts of literature.

This does not give much useful information. So, based on other questions, it doesn't look like it, but as always, there is always a spark of hope inside...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Probably not.

This site is for asking questions about written literature, and questions about related topics. If you have a question about writing techniques, you could try [Writing](https://writing.stackexchange.com). I don't think such a question would be on topic here, but you can always try and see what actually happens...

Comment: Questions about writing techniques are welcome on Writers as long as you are not posting a chunk of copy and asking for a critique. "How do I do X?" is generally okay. "Can I do X?" is usually met with "Sure, go for it." "If I do X, will that produce Y effect?" is also good.

Comment: Questions about writing techniques of the form: "How did James Joyce write *Ulysses*?" would certainly be on topic. And there's undoubtedly a gray area between questions like this and questions which are most probably off-topic.